# The confuse about use jquery $.ajax to read javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

suppose I have a config javascript file:

```
window.Config = {};

Config.UI = {
    "Area": {},
    "Layer": {},
    "Sprites": {},
    "Audio": {}
};

Config.UI.Area = {
    "prop": {
        "uuid": {
            "_type": "string",
        },
        "frame": {
            "_type": "rect",
            "_value": {
                "x": "0",
            },
            "_aka": "frame"
        },
        "zIndex": {
            "_type": "string",
        }
    },
```

then I want use $.ajax to read this file:

```
        $.ajax({
            url:'js/config.js',
            success:function (data, textStatus) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        })
```

the question is how can I get some key's value in the config,by use the data $.ajax return?

like the "Config.UI" or the 'uuid' in ui.area.prop?Or can I convert them to json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find it very useful and powerful to store data on the server as javascript objects and read them using Ajax. And it is very easy to do. Let me give you an example from an educational application I have written.

This is an example table of contents file (l1contents.js) that I would store on the server:

```
{
     title : "Lesson 1",
     topics : [
         {name : "Topic  1", file : "l1t1data.js" },
         {name : "Topic  2", file : "l1t2data.js" },
     ]
}
```

This is the javascript code I use to process the file:

```
    $.ajax({
        url : contentsFileName, // would be set to 'l1contents.js'
        dataType : 'text', // yes this is correct, I want jquery to think this is text
        cache : false,

        success: function(data) {
            var contentsObj = eval('(' + data + ')');
            var lessonTitle = contentsObj.title;
            for (var i = 0; i < contentsObj.topics.length; i++) {
                 var topic = contentsObj.topics [i];
                 // process topic.name and topic.file here
            }
        }
    });
```

Obviously, this is simplified, but hopefully you get the idea. I simply use eval to set the object. And note that I don't even need any javascript code defining the structure of contentsObj. (I, of course, do have extensive comments defining the structure of my objects, but they are simply comments, not code.)

Answer (score 5):

Rather than use AJAX, why not just insert a script?

```
var script = $('<script>');
script.attr('type', 'text/javascript');
script.attr('src', 'js/config.js');
script.bind('load', function() {
    // use window.Config
});
script.appendTo('head');
```

Comment: +1 Yes, I agree with this answer.  Don't use ajax to load a script file.  Inserting script tags makes it all automatic.

Comment: you do happen to know that there's a [`getScript()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) function in jQuery right?

Answer (score 1):

icktoofay has a good suggestion, and the issue with the jQuery.ajax call looks to be a missing `dataType: 'script'` option which will evaluate the response and should give you object access. You might want to look into [jQuery.getscript()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) as well.

Answer (score 0):

if your json file contains json data than you can use parseJSON() , toJSON() method.

and another solution is use eval(), this conver json data to javascript object so you can easly get a value by giving key.